# Icons don't show up in react-navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I am looking for Icons beside names on tab navigation but i i am getting this error:

[image]

I don't use expo then i imported by this way:

```
import { Ionicons } from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

And:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
```

This is the main code:

```
const MainTab=()=>{

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return(

<Tab.Navigator

screenOptions={({route})=>({
 tabBarIcon:({color, size})=>{
  let iconName;

  if (route.name=='Home') {

    iconName='ios-home'

  }else if(route.name=='Settings'){

  iconName='logo-settings'
 }

 return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
 }
})}
>


<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />

<Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SecondPage} />


</Tab.Navigator>

  )}
```

Which part have i made mistake?

Comment: Does it help if you remove the curly braces from your import of Ionicons?

Comment: The problem might be that React is trying to render the icon when no value has been given to `iconName`

Comment: @SydneyY  Thanks buddy your solution worked but i got another problem now, Icons don't show up properly, Please take a look at this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/SYM5fKB
As far as i know i have installed Ionicons (And please write your solution as answer i will vote for it)

Comment: Found it! If you're using the import Ionicons, the component is Ionicons, not Icon. `<Ionicons name={iconName} />`

Comment: @SydneyY I already did it, like this ```return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />``` but issue is persisting

Comment: `screenOptions={({route})=>({` this line, remove the last parentheses `(` and it's partner way down after Ionicons closes. Not sure if this is the issue. Also test removing some more curly braces from parameters like `({route})`, those curly braces are for extracting a key from an object.

Comment: I did right now but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement

```
import { Ionicons } from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

You are using the curly brackets to extract Ionicons from it's default export, but it *is* the default export, so simply:

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have faced this problem before so here are a few recommendations on how you can solve it additionally find attach working snippets for your reference in the bottom.

here are a couple of solutions:

1, With regards to this error message please be sure to check your files and insure you have exported your components correctly and into the right files.

2, In react-navigation v5 you generally should be able to export and import the components with out defining any navigation const inside the component file for example.. refer to the snippet //React navigation v5 / v4.

3, With regards to react-native-vector-icons please note that linking is automatic and if you link it manually you may get an error as an additional icon file is added to your xcode project. 
with regards to installation of react-native-vector-icons try the following steps:

• npm install react-native-vector-icons
• visit the info.plist files and paste the following fonts snippet (reference below // info.plist)
• cd ios run pod install and pod update.

```html
// info.plist

<dict>
 <key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
<string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
<string>Entypo.ttf</string>
<string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
<string>Feather.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
<string>Foundation.ttf</string>
<string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
<string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
<string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
<string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
<string>Octicons.ttf</string>
<string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>


// React navigation v5 working example


    import React from 'react'
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
    import HomeNavigator from '../containers/Home/HomeNavigator'
    import AccountNavigator from '../containers/Account/AccountNavigator'
    import FavouritesNavigator from '../containers/Favourites/FavouritesNavigator'
    import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'


    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

    function BottomTabs (){
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home';
            } else if (route.name === 'Account') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-person' : 'ios-person';
            }else if (route.name === 'Favourites') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-heart' : 'ios-heart';
            }



            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#547DD3',
          inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeNavigator} />
        <Tab.Screen name='Favourites' component={FavouritesNavigator} />
        <Tab.Screen name='Account' component={AccountNavigator} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      )
    }


    export default BottomTabs

//React navigation v5 / v4

    //v5
    export default Screen // into the navigation stack.

    //V4

    const  Screen = createStackNavigator({
      ScreenPage : {screen : ScreenPage},
    },{ mode: 'modal', headerMode: 'none'});
    export default Screen;
```